# Migrate Entity Framework 4.0 to Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, complextype

I have an old project developed with the Entity Framwork 4.0 which uses some complex types. Since I need to migrate it to .NET Core, I created a new project, installed all required libraries and used the command

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=ServerInstance; Database=DBName; Trusted_Connection=True;" 
             Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

on the existing database in order to create the new models. The problem is that it does not generate the complex type classes.

I can imagine I could replace the generated properties with by hand created complex types, use the `[ComplexType]` attribute and set the property using `OwnsOne` command, but I was wandering if there is a sort of auto generation option.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Databases have no notion (nor indication) of complex types, so there is no way to get that automatically (except if EF Core recognizes some some naming convention which I doubt). Most likely the complex types in the old system have been created/mapped manually, and you have to reconstruct them manually in EF Core (note that there is no `[ComplexType]` attribute in EF Core, you can use `Owned`, but column names have to be mapped with fluent API for each owner of the owned type).

Comment: You  do that inside `OwnsOne` method builder action - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652135/entity-framework-core-2-1-owned-types-and-nested-value-objects/53652438#53652438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a second partial class in order to add custom stuff to the created one. Added also a partial OnModelCreatingPartial method in which I define my complex types.

Here a snippet:

```
[Owned]
public class MyComplexType
{
    public bool AField { get; set; }
    public string BField { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyMainEntity
{
    public MyComplexType MyComplexType { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("myConnectionString",
                opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds)
            );
        }
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyMainEntity>().OwnsOne(e => e.MyComplexType, myComplexType =>
        {
            myComplexType.Property(p => p.AField).HasColumnName("ColumnNameFieldA");
            myComplexType.Property(p => p.BField).HasColumnName("ColumnNameFieldB");
        });
    }
}
```